# Visual Studio 2012- Find and Replace - backreferences

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012, replace

I have an XML file and want to replace every time value from seconds to milliseconds.

For instance, replace `time="250" to time="250000"`.

I tried using the following

> ```
> Find: time="([0-9]*)"
>
> Replace: time="$1000"
> ```

However, that does not seem to work - it replaces `time="250" to time="$1000"`. Any way I can get around this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your replace isn't `$1`, it is `$1000`. Visual Studio doesn't know that you don't want to include those 3 0's in your backreference.

You can use `{}` around your backreference to tell Visual Studio exactly what to use.

```
Replace: time="${1}000"
```

Obligatory note that Visual Studio 2010 and older used a different regular expression syntax, so this is only valid for Visual Studio 2012 (and presumably any newer versions).

Answer (score 1):

Have checked the "Find Options" expansion menu + checked the "Use Regular Expressions" checkbox?